# Tab Not Responding After Being Created At Runtime

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller, runtime

I'm pretty new to iOS but have been managing quite well so far with the help of a number of tutorials ( and questions from here! ). Unfortunately I've come across a bit of a problem, and while I'm sure I'm not the first person to ask this, I can't seem to find any related questions / answers.

I'm using Xcode 5 / iOS 7 & have created an iPad application which has Navigation Controller with a standard UIViewController as it's main view. From here I have three buttons which go off to various parts, one of which links to a TabBarController. The tabs need to be created at runtime as the number of tabs depends on a database value.

I created a XIB / UIViewController class using Xcode & have followed a couple of tutorials in order to create the tabs correctly, which all works ok.

```
SkyViewController    *svController;

skyControllers  = [ [ NSMutableArray alloc ] init ];

for( int i = 0; i < 3; i++ )
{
    svController    = [ [ SkyViewController alloc ] init ];

    [ svController.tabBarItem setTitle:[ NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%d", @"Controller ", i ] ];

    [ skyControllers addObject:svController ];
}

[ self setViewControllers:skyControllers animated:YES ];
```

The above code creates the tabs correctly & I can navigate via the tab bar with no problem.

The XIB which I am loading has a number of buttons on it & the problem is that the buttons on the first tab item don't respond to presses when the application first loads. If I change to the second / third tab, the buttons work fine & then if I switch back to the first tab again, the buttons are also fine.

I am calling the code above in the viewDidLoad method of the TabBarController.

Obviously I want the buttons on the first tab to work first time, rather than having to switch to another tab & then back, can anyone point me in the right direction?

If you need any more information, please let me know.

Thanks.

Comment: Color all sub views or print frame of all subviews..there seems to be some overlaping

Comment: I'm not sure that's the problem as surely the overlapping would still be there when I switched between the views?

Comment: OK, it seems as though the buttons don't work when they are on the right-hand side of the screen, which is rather odd. If I put four buttons on the view, going across the screen horizontally ( app is in landscape by the way ), the first three respond to the press but the fourth one doesn't, until I change tab & then change back? Any ideas?

Comment: buttons become unresponsive when they are below some view or out of the frame of view on which they are added...